# SSRS Multi Select Parameter, both Null and not null

Tags: reporting-services

I'm new to SSRS, and have been tasked with a report that allows users to select NULL, non NULL or both.

For example

```
Name | ID
BOB     1
ALICE   2
DAVE    NULL
ROGER   NULL
```

Users need to be able to select Records with an ID value and/or records with no ID value.
So it would be a multi select parameter (ID, NO ID , ALL).

I can make this work with a sql query, but am not sure how to make it work with user parameters that can be either, or or both.

The id field is a decimal.

Any advice for how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to include conditions like the following in the WHERE clause:

```
and (ID is null and 'NO ID' in @Parameter or
     ID is not null and 'ID' in @Parameter)
```

Alternatively, if the non-null ID values are always positive, you could use "NO ID" and "ID" as the parameter value labels, with the actual available *values* as 0 and 1 respectively, and use a condition like:

```
and sign(coalesce(ID, 0)) in @Parameter
```

(These conditions won't work in conventional SQL - where `@Parameter` will always be single-valued - but should work in SSRS.)

Answer (score 1):

In the general tab of your Report parameter. There is an option for **Allow Null Values**. Check that box.

Also update your query to

```
From UserTable
Where (ID IS NULL OR ID IN (@IDparam))
```

Here are links if you need to know more abut Multi Select parameters
http://jsimonbi.wordpress.com/2011/01/15/using-multi-select-with-stored-procedures/
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337396(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: This answer won't work correctly if the user selects non-null IDs only.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. In my solution `@IDparam` it will show values like *Select All, 1,2,3 and Null* instead of showing it as *ID, NO ID and ALL*. If this solution is implement the user would have option to Select an ID of value 1 or just 1 and 3 or 1 and Null and so on.